# How do I connect web component code to the finalization of the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, web-component

How do I delay execution of code inside my web component until the entire document is loaded and ready?

My web component needs to interact with elements outside of itself -- it will query the `body` tag for elements, and those those elements will usually appear *after* the web component in document order. So, the web component will be added to the DOM first.

Sure enough, in `connectedCallback`, none of those other elements can be found, I assume because they haven't been added to the DOM yet. If I move my web component lower on the page, it finds them just fine (presumably because they were added before the web component).

I have tried the traditional method of `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFunction)`, but the problem is that inside `myFunction`, `this` now references the HTML document, not my web component. So I'm executing code "outside" the web component, which is not what I want.

How can I do something on `DOMContentLoaded` and execute code in the context of my web component? Or how can I otherwise defer execution until the entire DOM has populated, no matter where on the page my web component sits?

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => myFunction())` or `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFunction.bind(thecomponent))`

Comment: Where would you put that? In the constructor?

Comment: Some stabs in the dark: use ``<script defer src="...">`` But use with care, why would you executed code too late? By your comments you also probably want to learn ``.bind(this)`` and the Mutation Observer API. Add code examples of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the event listener inside the connectedCallback, alternatively, you "could" use a setTimout( ()=>myfunction, 5000 ) to wait 5 seconds before running. "Hacky" but should work.

```js
class MyCustomWebComponent extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  myFunction(e) {
    // do the thing with the body elements
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => myFunction(e);) // using anonymous function will bind 'this' properly to myFunction
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event